# How do you cite math stack exchange pages in scientific papers?

Tags: discussion, citation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>
> http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/what-is-a-good-standard-for-publishing-a-reference-to-a-stackexchange-thread
>   [Research which began at the website](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860/research-which-began-at-the-website)

How you cite math stack exchange pages?

I'm writing a paper and need to cite: [Given two basis sets for a finite Hilbert space, does an unbiased vector exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28413/given-two-basis-sets-for-a-finite-hilbert-space-does-an-unbiased-vector-exist)