# Thesis: Should I list stackexchange in my bibliography and if so how?

Tags: discussion

I am writing a thesis and I shouldn't claim credit for things I haven't done/come up with. On the other hand, math.stackexchange is a bit shady as a source and listing it as such can therefore hurt my reputation. (I don't want to claim credit, I'd just rather not list the source.) What is the proper way to approach this problem?

I have used this forum for a proof for the identity $\Delta(z)=z\Delta(z+1)$ in  Weierstrass Gamma function.

Also, I have watched a tutorial on youtube to prove that Euler's constant $\gamma$ converges, which is an added bonus of sorts; it is part of an appendix. Should I cite this and if so how?

Comment: I feel this question is better off in the meta mathematics site since it doesn't pose any mathematical problem to the community.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4259/do-i-cite-mathematics-stack-exchange-in-my-thesis-paper https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2961/how-do-you-cite-math-stack-exchange-pages-in-scientific-papers https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4767/citing-a-person-on-mse https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8212/citing-stackexchange-postings and probably, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation

Comment: Check with your thesis advisor. Internet sources are becoming more common, and surely there is a standard way of referring to them. And, I don't think Math.SE is shady. I have seen instances when we offer more accurate information than, say, Wikipedia. Mind you, WP has improved a lot since its early days, but still some of the things I see there make me shake my head (in areas where I think I can justifiable call myself an expert).

Comment: In most cases Math.SE posts will be *secondary* references, rather than *primary* references (sources reflecting original research and findings).  I point this out not to discourage your citation of Math.SE posts, but to advise checking the writing guidelines for your thesis and its bibliography for appropriate use of references.